# background image transparent

Tags: css, image, background-color

how can I set all image backgrounds transparent when I preview them inside a container? I want to set the background of an image transparent only the ones with white backgrounds. I don't want to use opacity it makes the rest of the image dull.

```
.image
{
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background:transparent;
opacity: 0.6;
}
```

Comment: `background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0)`

Comment: like this           .image
{
 width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);

 }

Comment: That'll work, but there's no way CSS/HTML can make the white areas of an actual image transparent. For that you'd have to use an image editor like Photoshop or freeware like Paint.NET.  A .PNG or .GIF has transparent capabilities.

Comment: sorry this doesn't work for me I have seen this work in other websites like customink.com what I want to do is for users to upload an image and have a background transparent. thank you for your time

Comment: erm..those are exactly what I was saying. Those are just images edited with  with a program to have an alpha transparency. http://www.customink.com/assets/site_content/pages/homepage_v2/home-products-laydown-53327fe8cbfddc225d733820c0241413cfb30ae641338f15551189166ae42567.png Note that this is an PNG image file. This particular image is displayed by the CSS property `background-image`. If you want uploaded files to be altered programmatically, then you need to use a server-side function from PHP, Python, etc.